# Thread-safe CreateThread?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

Is the `PrintHello()` function pthreads example thread-safe? I find these kind of examples online but I don't understand how they can be thread-safe. On the other hand, if I add a mutex around the code in `PrintHello()` function then the example would not be multithreaded as all threads would queue in wait for the previous thread to exit the `PrintHello()` function. Also, moving it to a class would not help as the member would have to be statically declared as pointers to non-static functions is not allowed with `CreateThread()` it seems. Any way of solving this?

```
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

#define NUM_THREADS     500

DWORD PrintHello(LPVOID oHdlRequest)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)GetCurrentThreadId();

   /* randomly sleep between 1 and 10 seconds */
   int sleepTime = rand() % 10 + 1;   
   sleep(sleepTime);

   printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
   return 0;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   /* initialize random seed: */
   srand (time(NULL));

   HANDLE threads[NUM_THREADS];
   long t;
   DWORD nThreadID;

   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
      printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);

      threads[t] = CreateThread(
            // Default security
            NULL, 
            // Default stack size
            0, 
            // Function to execute
            (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&PrintHello,
            // Thread argument
            NULL,
            // Start the new thread immediately
            0, 
            // Thread Id
            &nThreadID
        );    

      if (!threads[t]){
         printf("ERROR; return code from CreateThread() is %d\n", GetLastError());
         exit(-1);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "thread safe". Safe from *what*?

Comment: @dlev http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety " A piece of code is thread-safe if it only manipulates shared data structures in a manner that guarantees safe execution by multiple threads at the same time". In the simple example above it would entail that the `printf` may echo the wrong thread ID.

Comment: That definition says that thread safety is code execution that is "safe". That is not very helpful :). Regardless, my point is that it is hard to define what safe means for threads: no crashes? Consistent data for callers? Up to date data? In this case, the code does not appear to be manipulating shared state, so I guess by the above definition it is trivially "thread safe". That said, I encourage you to read this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx

Comment: @IngeHenriksen: That definition is oversimplified. Besides, where are the shared data structures here? Also, why would it print the wrong id?

Comment: Yes, this code is not thread-safe, bacause `printf` internally works with global data, the output may be corrupted. To make it thread-safe, protect `printf` execution with critical section. Protected code section should be minimal, in this case - only `printf` code, and not entire `ProcessRequest` function.

Comment: Notice that arguments passed to `printf` are OK, but global output stream used by `printf` from different calls is not synchronised. To hide this effect, random sleep is used. Remove sleep and increase total threads number - you have chance to see corrupted output.

Comment: @dlev Ex. `tid` is set to `1000` by thread #1, then thread #1 sleeps for 10 seconds, while it sleeps thread #2 sets `tid` to `1001`, sleeps for 1 seconds and leaves `ProcessRequest()`, then thread #1 wakes up and prints `Hello World! It's me, thread #1001!` which is the wrong thread id.

Comment: tid is a local variable, which will be allocated on the stack. Each thread will have its own stack, and thus its own copy of the variable. It is not shared state. Alex's point about global structures is also relevant, though not really what you had in mind, I think :)

Comment: You can use `sprintf` for formatting, and then use a thread-safe OS function such as `write` for the actual printing.

Comment: `printf( ... )` is defined as `fprintf( stdout, ... )`.  `stdout` is shared state.  Note that `sleep` is not guaranteed to be reentrant either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're including `WinBase.h`, I'll assume that you're using MSVC. MSVC CRT has long supported multithreaded access - in fact, current versions of MSVC no longer support a single threaded CRT that isn't threadsafe. I believe that VS 2003 is the last version of MSVC that supported the single threaded CRT.

In the multithreaded CRT, functions are threadsafe and if they access global data internally they will synchronize among themselves. So each `printf()` executed in `ProcessRequest()` will be atomic with respect to other `printf()` calls in other threads (actually, the locks are based on streams, so the `printf()` calls will be atomic with respect to other CRT functions that use `stdout`).

The exceptions to this are if you use I/O functions that are explicitly documented to not take locks (so you can synchronize on them yourself for performance reasons), or if you define `_CRT_DISABLE_PERFCRIT_LOCKS` in which case the CRT assumes that all I/O will be performed on a single thread.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235505.aspx

POSIX makes similar guarantees that `printf()` will be threadsafe:

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html

  > All functions that reference (FILE *) objects, except those with names ending in _unlocked, shall behave as if they use flockfile() and funlockfile() internally to obtain ownership of these (FILE *) objects.
- http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.programming.threads/2009-06/msg00058.html (A post by David Butenhof):

  > POSIX/UNIX requires that printf() itself be atomic; it's not legal that two parallel calls to printf() from separate threads can mix their data. But those two writes may appear on the output in either order.

Comment: If locks are based on streams then `printf("%d%d",x,y)` is not completely thread safe, because it would lock the stream two times.

Comment: @Dialecticus: Why would it lock the stream two times?  `printf()` locks the stream, performs the I/O, then unlocks the stream.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I thought `printf` is calling some other, lower level, function, that actually locks the stream.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not thread-safe in general; `printf` is not normally
reentrant.  (An implementation could add reentrace to it as
an additional feature, but I don't know of any which do.)  You
must add some sort of protection around it.  (Under Windows,
a so called `CriticalSection` should be sufficient.)

You'll also have to find a thread safe alternative to `sleep`;
I can't find any documentation which says that it is reentrant
(and the Posix variant isn't), but Microsoft doesn't seem to
document reentrance in general.  A classical solution for this
would be to create a Mutex, block it, and then call
`WaitForSingleObject` on it with the desired timeout;
`CreateWaitableTimer` and `WaitForSingleObject` should work as
well.  (As I said, Microsoft's documentation is very deficient;
but `WaitForSingleObject` must be safe, since it is des igned to
be used when waiting for a mutex, among other things.)

Note too that unless you join the created threads, you'll
probably run off the end of `main`, and the process will
terminate before any of the threads will have run.  (Under
Windows, you can use `WaitForSingleObject` or
`WaitForMultipleObjects` to join.)

An even better solution would be to the standard threads, if you
have a compiler which supports them, or Boost threds, if you
don't.